# Xamarin.Android. Setting time for LongClick event

Tags: c#, android, events, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible in Xamarin.Android to set event `LongClick` click time or something similar? The click time as it is, is too short for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LongClick timing is managed by the Android OS, so it cannot be directly modified. However, you could go around the problem by handling everything by yourself.

1. Create a touch listener.
2. In the OnTouch event, detect if the touch action is `MotionEventActions.Down` and get the current time in milliseconds by using [CurrentTimeMillis](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis/) method.
3. Have another check for `MotionEventActions.Up` to detect when the user lifts the finger. Calculate the time difference between touch up and touch down events and if it's long enough, do something.

[Here's](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/) some code samples related to touch events. It shows how to create the touch listener and react to touch events.

Comment: But i had ripple effect and after this effect gone. Maybe you know why ?

Comment: @armandasalmd I can't say for sure since I don't have an access to a computer just now. Maybe you could open a new question since you have a clear problem that should easy to reproduce?